# Sorting the list of dictionaries in descending order of a particular key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries in python, for example

```
[{'a':3, 'b':4, 'c':5, 'd':'6'}, {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':7, 'd':'9'}]
```

I want to sort it based on the value of 'c' in descending order. I tried using `sorted()` method using `key = lambda` but no help.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 31):

There are lots of ways to write this.  Before you're comfortable with lambdas, the best thing to do is write it out explicitly:

```
def sort_key(d):
    return d['c']

sorted(list_of_dict, key=sort_key, reverse=True)
```

A trained eye will see that this is the same as the following one-liner:

```
sorted(list_of_dict, key=lambda d: d['c'], reverse=True)
```

Or, possibly:

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(list_of_dict, key=itemgetter('c'), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import operator
list_of_dicts.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('c'), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Up-voted. But also mention `reverse=True` as OP requested the order to be the descending